# DTO pattern with JPA hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dto

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application) about DTO and checking the way to convert Entity to DTO. I wonder what's the meaning of lazy relationship, if in the moment of converting it to DTO, I need to get the data in order to set it into the DTO class? I always need to get the data first, so does it matter if I set it lazy or eager?

Comment: It depends on the specifics of your serialization. In particular, if you're only using IDs to serialize related entities (a good idea to avoid cycles), your JPA provider might not need to fetch the lazy entities.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean.., following the idea of this tutorial it transfer all the data from the entity to the DTO and then use the DTO to operate.

Comment: Going above the turorial, things get interesting if your DTO is a not a direct mapping of your persistent entities. What if your DTO is an aggregation of two different objects, together, that does not need any related entity ? Lazy fetching, then is a win.  It's a tradeoff (or a case by case tuning) between wanting to fetch data upfront (and how you want to fetch it, e.g. JOIN vs. a separate SELECT), versus just in time.

Comment: If I have one/two entities with lazy relations , in the moment it is mapped with the DTO I need to get the data from the child so, it has no sense have a lazy relationship.. 
I need to have all the data in the DTO because I dont know when it's going to be needed..I'm not sure if you see my point.. maybe I'm not explaining properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you move your point of view out of "what will my DTO need", as this clouds the judgment.

Eager vs. lazy is rather a design tradeoff between "how often will I need the relationships loaded", vs. "how much can it cost to load the relationship" ?

Take an extrême example. You have a persistent entity, say a `Region`. A `Region` has a relationships to all people (`Person` entity) living in this `Region`. And people (`Person`) can know each other.

Let's imagine you `eager` fetch everything in this entity graph, and you have a requirement to load all regions for a screen (not the people, only the regions).

Loading all `Region` will eagerly load all `Person` living there. But as people know each other and this will be eagerly loaded too, then you load up the **entire database** into memory just to display regions.

Loading the whole database into memory usually is an unacceptable cost.

Wait. There's worse.

Say I want to edit a single `Person`. So I load it. This eagerly fetches the `Person`'s `Region`. Which eagerly fetches all `Person` instances in this region. And it also fetches all other `Person`s this one knows of, which in turn fetches those other `Person`'s `Region`, and recursively all the way down.

Even for a single `Perosn` I've loaded the whole database again.

Does that mean you should never have eager fetching ? No.

What it does mean is : you can put eager fetching when you know that data is often needed together, AND you can control the amount of data the fetching will incur, directly AND indirectly.

This is what is at stake : do not load your entire 200 million rows table for a single entity.

Comment: Ok understood. Anyway, I was thinking in something that map the DTO to the entity in the way that when you ask for the People of the Region to the DTO it go to the entity and it request the data to the db, dont know if this is possible or exist or whatever. Anyway, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

In lazy loading child class values are loaded only when getter of child classes are explicitly called. But for eager loading, while invoking parent all its child class have value already loaded in it.
Eager loading is slower and consumes more memory compared to lazy loading.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the question, I know the difference and I know the kind of fetch mode, please, read again the question